# Developing on a 64bit machine when the production is 32bit

Tags: .net, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, gac, 32-bit

I have a 64 bit machine for the last year or so and I develop to a production which runs 32bit.

So far I had no problems.

I've been told that I need to replace my workstation so it will run 32 bit.
one of his reasons was that there might be some issues so that some dlls which are taken from the GAC are designed for 64bit and may work on my computer but when released to production errors may occur.

Is it correct about the GAC?

Should I replace the workstation? are there other reasons why it should be replaced?

Comment: +vote up for nice question! Looking forward for some opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what continuous integration is built for. Get a 32-bit CI environment setup to test your changes after every commit. This way you will know your changes work on your production environment.

By moving your build process to a dedicated machine that has a similar setup to your production machine you can build and test more reliably. It is good for getting rid of the "works for me" issues as if it doesn't build on the CI server, then something has gone wrong.

See [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) and [here](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/integrateoften.html) for more information.

Comment: can you expand a little bit on the subject?

Comment: +1 If the process at work is that you build something on your box and push it into development, the 64 bit machine is the least of the company's worries.  You should check in source code, and the source code should be checked out on a dedicated build machine (can be a virtual machine) and built there along with every one else's source code changes.

Comment: @jamesj We have a dedicated build machine running nightly builds. It holds all the code and its TFS version controlled.

Comment: @Mithir - you can set TFS up to do build on every commit. This is CI. If you have a different machine building your releases for production then you shouldn't need to replace your machine. If you run into trouble with debugging or soemthing then install a VM, but replacing it is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should keep your beast of a machine and do development there. You can either get a Windows VM or another machine to do all of your testing, verification and debugging there.

Comment: I don't mind formatting, I just want to know if the reasons are correct, are they?